# JacksonProviderProxy writing out null values in json output

Tags: json, jackson

I have a simple POJO class that extends another simple POJO class. I am using the `com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy` to marshall the properties in these POJO classes to JSON. However, when I set some of the properties to the POJO as `null`, then it outputs those properties as the string `null` instead of not outputting it at all.

for eg.

```
{
   Person:
   [{
      "firstName":"John"
      "lastName":"null"
    }]
}
```

instead of:

for eg.

```
{
   Person:
   [{
      "firstName":"John"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do this in a web app. So any pointers as to how to confiure this in a web application would be great.

Answer (score 18):

Different options are available for suppressing serialization of properties with null values, depending on the version of Jackson in use, and whether the `ObjectMapper` can be directly configured.

With Jackson 1.1+, with direct access to configure the `ObjectMapper`, you could just call [`setSerializationInclusion`](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setSerializationInclusion%28com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include%29)([`Include.NON_NULL`](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_NULL)).

Alternatively, you could annotate the (class) type that has the properties, for which null properties serialization is to be suppressed, with [`@JsonSerialize`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.html)([`include`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.html#include%28%29)`=`[`Inclusion.NON_NULL`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/annotate/JsonSerialize.Inclusion.html#NON_NULL)).

With Jackson 2+, instead of the `@JsonSerialize` annotation, use [`@JsonInclude`](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.html?is-external=true)([`Include.NON_NULL`](http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_NULL)).